# If a string is enclosed in quotes either " or '. I have to remove those starting and ending quotes in snowflake

Tags: sql, regex, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

Check the following input/output examples:

1. Input: `""Nag"ndra""` -> Expected output: `"Nag"ndra"`
2. Input: `'N'agendra` -> Expected output `'N'agendra`

I tried the below query to implement that behavior, which is able to remove the starting and ending quotes.

```
select regexp_replace('""Nag"endra""','^["\']|["\']$','') from dual
```

for second example it is given as `N'agendra` it should be  `'N'agendra`

Comment: in Snowflake you don't have to `select X from dual`, you can just `SELECT 123 as number;`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to keep the starting **'** then don't use it in the regex. This works for me:

```
select regexp_replace('""Nag"endra""','^["]|["\']$',''); -- "Nag"endra"
select regexp_replace('\'N\'agendra','^["]|["\']$',''); -- 'N'agendra
```

Observe I removed the **'** from **^["\']**.

Answer (score 0):

If the regex flavour supports backreferences to a capturing group inside the expression, you could match the delimiter at the beginning of the string and reference it at the end, then replace by the contents of a second capturing group:

```
SELECT REGEXP_REPLACE( '""Nag"ndra""', '^(["\'])(.*)\\1$', '$2' );
```

If it does not, but supports backreferences in the replacement part, you could use two calls. For example:

```
SELECT REGEXP_REPLACE( '""Nag"ndra""', '^"(.*)"$', '$1' );
SELECT REGEXP_REPLACE( '\'N\'agendra', '^\'(.*)\'$', '$1' );
```

You'd probably want to test for the existence of a matched pair of quotes first, then select the one you need if you only want to remove the outer pair of quotes in this case.

**Edit** If neither is supported, you could use a conditional and your own expression. You have to make sure that your beginning quotes are matched at the end first:

```
SELECT IF(
    '""Nag"ndra""' REGEXP '^".*"$|^\'.*\'$',
    REGEXP_REPLACE( '""Nag"ndra""', '^["\']|["\']$', '' ), 
    '""Nag"ndra""'
);
```

Comment: Snowflake does not support backreferencing.

Answer (score 0):

You could just use logic, decomposed to see it working:

```
SELECT 
    column1,
    LEFT(column1,1) as first_char,
    RIGHT(column1,1) as last_char,
    SUBSTR(column1,2, LENGTH(column1)+2) as truncated,
    IFF(first_char = last_char AND (first_char = '"' OR first_char = '\''), truncated, column1) as cleaned
FROM values ('""Nag"ndra""'), ('\'N\'agendra ');
```

gives:

| COLUMN1 | FIRST_CHAR | LAST_CHAR | TRUNCATED | CLEANED |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| ""Nag"ndra"" | " | " | "Nag"ndra"" | "Nag"ndra"" |
| 'N'agendra | ' |  | N'agendra | 'N'agendra |

and composing it together:

```
SELECT 
    column1,
    IFF(LEFT(column1,1) = RIGHT(column1,1) AND LEFT(column1,1) in ('"', '\''), SUBSTR(column1,2, LENGTH(column1)+2), column1) as cleaned
```

gives:

COLUMN1 |CLEANED
--|--
""Nag"ndra""    |"Nag"ndra""
'N'agendra  |'N'agendra
FROM values ('""Nag"ndra""'), (''N'agendra ');